# WP header reload

Tags: php, header, wordpress, reload

I am new to wordpress plugin development. I made some coding and understand enough about making the menu -- sub-menu etc. In one sub-menu page I made a form that changes the email id in one of mytable in database. But to stop data inserting on page reload/refresh/page-back I have to give a header function but I am unable to do the same.

In more simple words I just want to stop wordpress plugin to inserting/update data in table on page refresh. Please read my coding below.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label><b>Mention Your Email Here :</b></label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email here"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="set" id="set" value="CHANGE"/>
</form>

<br/><br/>

<u>NOTE</u> :<br/>
1. Please write your email id in the field given above. This email id will be used to get emails of visitors contact query.
<br/>
2. Copy the shortcode given below to show the form on the website.<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>[myplugin]</b>

<?php

//getting the form email id value

if (isset($_POST['set']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "myemail";
    $result = $wpdb->update($table_name, array('id' => '1', 'email' => $email), array('id' => '1'));

    if ($result > 0) {
        echo "<script>alert('Successfully Updated');</script>";
    } else {
        exit(var_dump($wpdb->last_query));
    }

    $wpdb->flush();
} else {
    header('location: ------?????--------------');
}

?>
```

In header what should I write so the page comes to same page after reload. But without inserting/updating data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redirect to the same page with:

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit();
```

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> 'REQUEST_URI'
>   The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.

For `header()` to work, the form processing script would need to run before HTML is output, so you'd need to hook it to an appropriate WP action hook (e.g. 'wp'). The form would be in a template or include, and the processing function hooked by means of the WordPress `add_action()`. You'd also need to sanitize the data before saving to the database.